# inserting JSON file to the postgres by using Shell scripting

Tags: postgresql, shell, google-cloud-platform

i have a json file, i need to create a postgres table based on some keywords like serviceName, methodName, resourceName, request, insertId, timestamp, severity etc., how to get that specific values to the postgres table by using shell scripting.

Json File:

```
  {
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {},
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "charan@gmail.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "2409:4070:212:dbcc:493a:5fb4:ceda:97ee",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2021-01-25T03:52:18.098132320Z",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "storage.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "storage.objects.get",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/_/buckets/devops-297210_cloudbuild/objects/perfect-precept-292004-cb1f649787fc.json",
        "permission": "storage.objects.get",
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      },
      {
        "resource": "projects/_/buckets/devops-297210_cloudbuild",
        "permission": "storage.objects.list",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/_/buckets/devops-297210_cloudbuild/objects/perfect-precept-292004-cb1f649787fc.json",
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "us"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "-1nb9yxef6ea0",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gcs_bucket",
    "labels": {
      "bucket_name": "devops-297210_cloudbuild",
      "location": "us",
      "project_id": "devops-297210"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-01-25T03:52:18.091308598Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/devops-297210/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-25T03:52:18.583690101Z"
```

Comment: Do you have multiple log entry in your JSON file? If so, what's the structure? the JSON is inline or pretty printed as in your example? Do you have an array of log entry in JSON?

Comment: You can install and use utility `jq` in shell for parsing strings in your JSON-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use utility `jq` for parsing strings of your JSON-file and then insert values to postgres table with shell or script.
More information: https://medium.com/lcom-techblog/transform-json-data-with-jq-533fa43bedc0

Installing:

```sh
wget -O jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
chmod +x ./jq
cp jq /usr/bin
```

Execute shell command to get `serviceName` value from `file.json`:

```sh
jq '.protoPayload.serviceName' file.json | tr -d '"'
```

Output:

```
storage.googleapis.com
```